# Does Captain America have a 'No-Kill' policy?

Tags: marvel, captain-america

Captain America has been a soldier, so it is fair to say that he would have had his fair share of kills, but as a superhero **does Captain America Kill?**

i.e. does he have a 'no kill' policy similar to some incarnations of Batman?

I know that in the movies, we clearly see that he doesn't really hold back from killing enemies; is it the same in the comics?

Comment: "He's a soldier.  He's *the* soldier." Soldiers are required to take lives when necessary, period.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[He had no problem killing people during the war](http://goodcomics.comicbookresources.com/2014/03/22/the-abandoned-an-forsaked-so-did-captain-america-kill-people-during-world-war-ii-or-what/).
[image: Captain America #2]

He's killed people outside of war, but generally shows remorse over it.
[image: Captain America #321-322]

You can find more examples at the link above, but the long and the short of it is that Steve Rogers is the epitome of a good soldier. He doesn't want to kill, but he will when it's the best solution.

Comment: Both of those examples seem like they come from older comics.  Does the same pattern of remorse hold up in more modern storylines?

Comment: @Nerrolken I've added an answer that shows some more modern examples.

Answer (score 8):

In more modern incarnations, Captain America doesn't have a problem with killing.

Given his propensity to burst through doors and fire indiscriminately:

[image]

Or destroy a squadron of operational and manned flying death fortresses:

[image]

And even in the comics as recently as the Civil War storyline, he wasn't exactly gentle with people who got in his way:

[image]

Comment: In your first example, this is during World War 2 where he is a soldier. Putting it very simply, if a soldier shoots and kills an enemy then no great problem. If that same soldier comes home and shoots and kills a criminal, then big problem.

Comment: In the second example he kills aliens that are attacking and killing people. Morally that is the same as killing a dangerous animal to save humans, in other words killing something non-human that is killing humans. Admittedly this morality is very much open to question, but ignoring personal feelings, that is it down to it's base level.

Comment: That second shot is a down helicarrier from Wintrr Soldier and is filled with people - who we are hoping are mostly HYDRA. Lots of people, lots of death.

Comment: And in the third example, not being exactly gentle with someone is a long long way from killing them. In Civil War, where you took the third example, there are two examples of people being killed (that I can remember off the top of my head) that involve Captain America in some way. When Ragnarok (the clone of Thor) kills Goliath, everyone is shocked and the battle pretty much ends right there, with both sides going their separate ways. And when the Punisher kills two criminal joining Cap's side Captain America beats him severely for killing and kicks him out of the group.

Comment: As has been pointed out, the second shot is a downed helicarrier from Winter Soldier. A helicarrier which was shot down by other helicarriers, not directly by Captain America. Yes he did change the chip over on two of the three helicarriers causing them to target each other but he did not shoot them down himself, therefore it's something of a grey area as to did he actually kill whatever people were on the helicarriers.

Comment: **"Look, I just pointed the gun, and pulled the trigger, but it was really the bullet that killed you."**

Comment: "Look, I just pointed the gun, and pulled the trigger, but it was really the bullet that killed you."                    More like I pointed the gun, and someone else pulled the trigger.

Comment: Even more like "Look, the trigger was already pulled, I just pointed the guns away from the innocents and at each other."